# Pass Object Property to a function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a object:

```
{
  user: activated: true;
  createdAt: "2020-07-29T22:19:51.053Z";
  email: "db2@bahn.com";
  updatedAt: "2020-08-02T13:07:48.992Z";
  _id: "5f21f6079f28a2095089c96a";
  __proto__: Object;
  __proto__: Object;
}
```

[image]
I'm looking way to pass email property from User Object to billing_address in Stripe createPaymentMethod:

```
import React from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const CheckoutForm = (user) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  console.log(user);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        email: user.email,
      },
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log("[error]", error);
    } else {
      console.log("[PaymentMethod]", paymentMethod);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form style={{ width: "400px" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Till now I have tried Object.values(user) and mapping function, but no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you've described as your object is an invalid object literal (`user: activated: true;` is a syntax error, as are all the other `;`s). That means we don't know what your actual object structure is, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: `user.email` would be correct if you have a `user` variable that refers to an object with an `email` property.

Comment: If CheckoutForm is a component, user is gonna be inside your props else from where are you calling CheckoutForm?

Comment: I've updated what I am getting from console.log(user);

CheckoutForm is a component where I am passing user props only when is called.